# How to convert weekdays to binary representation and vise versa using PHP

Tags: php

I am looking for PHP class that could convert any combination of weekdays to binary and vise versa

0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

Example:

- Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday => 0111110 (where sunday and saturday is off day)
- 0101010 => this binary represents Monday, Wednesday , Friday is ON other are OFF days

The class should be able to convert the binary to weekdays and weekdays to binary

The class could have two methods:

- public function convertWeekdaysToBinary($days)

  - This one will convert the coming days (array) to binary (string)
- public function convertBinaryToWeekdays($binary)

  - This one will convert the coming binary (string) to days (array)

Comment: good, simple and easy. What you tried for???

Comment: Seems like you already have a good idea of what you want, such a class would be simple to code. Why not try it yourself?

Comment: that is what i want to mean.

Comment: I am actually wondering which php functions could help me to accomplish that for example one of method of a class will receive the array of weekdays  which could be any of days now how to convert them to binary and return that binary and same for how to convert binary back to weekdays using another method

Comment: @JunaidAli, check the answer now.

Comment: do one really need a class to do it? Just a function would do... the question is unclear.. what have you done so far? and what is preventing you from reaching the final code?

Comment: yes I am writing a specialized class to do this I wrote the test for that aswell but I was not clear how to map the days to binary but the code provided by @FrayneKonok helps me a lot I am doing testing on that and extending it as per my requirement thanks FrayneKonok I will update you about result soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is for first:**

```
$arr = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');

$search1 = "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday";
$search_arr = explode(", ", $search1);
$out1 = array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0");
foreach($search_arr as $value){
    $sr = array_search($value, $arr);
    $out1[$sr] = "1";
}
echo implode("", $out1); //0111110
```

**Vice-versa**

```
$search2 = "0101010";
$search_arr = str_split($search2);
$out2 = array();
foreach($search_arr as $key => $value){
    if($value == 1){
        $out2[] = $arr[$key];
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $out2);//Monday, Wednesday, Friday
```